# Woocommerce Cart: Override or filter get_cart_item_quantities()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

For the products in a cake shop, the cakes can get ordered for different order dates (order attribute) within the same order.

The stock should only be considered, if the cakes are ordered for the next day. For orders further in the future, the stock is irrelevant.

So I want to modify the cart that in `get_cart_item_quantities()` the item quantities get only grouped for cakes ordered for the next day.

So far, I managed to write a plugin extending the original cart and `overriding get_cart_item_quantities()`and `add_to_cart()`.

But with the recent update, the plugin is no longer working due to new class hierarchies.

So I'm looking for a solution with standard filters and actions which is more update proof.

Can anyone help?

**Here's more information on what I want to achieve:**

The cakes can be ordered as a whole cake (12 or 16 pieces) – which is the main product – or as a variation of a quarter cake (3 or 4 pieces).
The shop keeper wants to **manage the stock in number of pieces for the whole cake**, not with the variations as well.

Moreover, the cakes can be ordered for next day delivery or sometime in the further future.

ONLY if the cake gets ordered for the next day, the stock should get checked.

Let's say there is 12 pieces of a cake in stock.

One customer buys a whole cake (12 pieces in this case) for tomorrow and a quarter for sometime next week.

**When adding this to the cart**, the cart should contain:

- amount 1 of the whole cake for tomorrow
- amount 1 of the quarter cake for sometime later

I add the delivery date in `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data`.

Internally, `WC_Product::has_enough_stock()` should check the stock only for the items ordered for tomorrow and in the actual number of pieces, in this case 12 for the whole cake for tomorrow (even though the amount in the cart is 1)

So far, I implemented the number of pieces by overriding `WC_Cart::get_cart_item_quantities()` and adding a custom filter.

And by overriding `WC_Cart::add_to_cart()` to modify `has_enough_stock()`.

During checkout, I reduce the stock amount by the correct number of pieces by filtering `woocommerce_order_item_quantity`.

But of course, with the plugin solution I need to update the plugin with almost every update of WooCommerce.

**The possibilities I see at the moment:**

As `WC_Product::has_enough_stock()` is not applying any filters itself, I could filter `woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity` and return the actual quantity if the delivery date is relevant and return a fake number like 9999 in all other cases.

Like this, stock management should workg during add to cart, in the cart and during checkout when relevant.

What do you think?

Comment: Hello, if i did understand the use case, i will suggest checking this filter  `woocommerce_add_cart_item` and this action `woocommerce_add_to_cart`. if it does not help, please explain more, may be provide some of your plugin code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @JBoulhous! I added now more information about the use case.

Comment: Hello @Miglosh, I think this has to be done with other logic than stock, as this is not actual stock, this is tomorrow stock, i would suggest using booking logic. There is an example by Woocommerce/Wordpress team using Bookings extension which is 249$ and you can get only the code otherway for 5 to 20$. this [example](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bookings-use-case-selling-limited-products-daily-bakery/) is probably similar to yours. Sorry for not providing an actual solution.

Comment: @Miglosh I have a very similar issue. Could you share your solution?